# Where to add Google Remarketing tag in Magento

Tags: magento, google-ads-api

I am trying to figure out in which file I need to add the Google remarketing tag. I know it needs to be added before the closing of the body tag. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is I did in the past:
Depending on what kind of google tracking you are using you have a few different way to use:

1) If only add a custom code and should be in all the Magento page, use the "Miscellaneous Scripts" value going to admin section, System > Configuration > Design > HTML Head - Miscellaneous Scripts. *(This will be included before head closing tag in page HTML.)*

2) By native Magento already have Google Analytics tracking code and you can find this configuration going to admin section System > Configuration > Google API - Google Analytics.

3) If you are looking something more complex and use the Google adWords I used the extension [magento connect link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/luka-google-adwords-conversion-tracking.html). For a particular Client I did some extra modification to include some extra code if a client subscribe to newsletter or a new client etc.

I hope you can find something helpfully in the post.

Best,
GrinGo.

Answer (score 0):

There are different template file for different pages in magento so at first I think you should decide where to place it.For example if you want to place it in footer than you should place that code snippet in

> "app/design/frontend/base/default/page/html/footer.phtml"

Similarly you can check other different template files to place your code.

NB:Best practice is to overide the core file of magento before making changes to it.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no indication as to which Magento version you're using 1 or 2. At the end of the day it depends how much technical knowledge you have and if you're using a version control system to manage your Magento build.

- **Miscellaneous Scripts** as another answer mentioned earlier, this approach is straight forward and very easy to use to plug and play your code.
- **Google Module** depending which version of Magento you use (CE/EE) there will be a built-in section for you to plugin your account ID in backend Magento configuration and then the platform will generate necessary code for you.
- **Write custom module** by writing your own module you can place it the snippet anywhere on the page by targeting `before_body_end` node in your layout XML file. This is more technical but gives you more control over what you can do.
- **Google Tag Manager** this also depends on if your Magento version comes pre-built with Google Tag Manager module, then you can create a container and place all your logic in there. This is also more technical and require the output of some values in JS format on the frontend to let GTM read the values.

At the end of the day go with what is **easy to setup, portable and easy to manage**. I usually go with Google Tag Manager as it takes time to create initial setup of exposing data on the frontend but then I have full control of what I want to do with that data through tag manager. In most cases you'll end up using the same data (ex. totals, shipping  method, product IDs, SKUs, cost, etc.) in more than one third party API so this gives you flexibility to do just that.